# How to produce only devanagari vowel signs (matra)?

Tags: pdftex, symbols, luatex, indic

Using texlive 2015 on OSX, and package devanagari, I can't seem to produce only vowel signs in devanagari? I'd like to be able to write only the matras for, for example a, o, and so on.

I've tried looking at the manual for devanagari, and there it is produced with `{\dn o}` But when trying, I only get the normal vowel 'o'.

In the manual, the matra for 'aa' is produced by `{\dn\symbol{'101}}` but this only produces an error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\protect 
l.11 {\dn \symbol{\rn{101}}
                         }
```

Here is a minimal non-working (ends with the error above) example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}

{\dn acchA}

{\dn o}

{\dn \symbol{'101}}

\end{document}
```

The first line works (acchaa).
The second line produces the vowel o (not the matra).
The third line produces the matra for short u and 101.

I've tried with both pdflatex and (my usual preference) lualatex with the same results. I'm running it through the devnag preprocessor, before pdf/lualatex.

[Update 1:]

If I *don't* run it through the preprocessor (`devnag`), but instead run `lualatex` directly on the minimal working example above, I get the matras I want --- but alas 'acchaa' does not print as expected, instead it's written like aa-ca-ca-ha-aa-aa. How can I get both; that is, that normally `{\dn acchaa}` would print "as expected", but in some specific cases (when I only want matras), it would interpret it differently?

[Update 2:]

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but if I use `{\dnoriginal o}` instead of `{\dn o}` I get the result I wanted. Even the `\symbol{'101}` works. So the minimal working example would thus be modified to the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}
\begin{document}

{\dn acchA}

{\dnoriginal o}

{\dnoriginal \symbol{'101}}

\end{document}
```

The above, processed first by `devnag` and then by `lualatex`, results in only matras for o and a (the lines with `\dnoriginal`) but acchaa is output as desired (not aacacahaaa, but acchaa).

So, case closed I guess!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: What manual are you referring to?

Comment: @egreg The manual for [the package devanagari](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/language/devanagari/velthuis/).

Comment: I see no trace of `\symbol{'101}` in that document.

Comment: @egreg You need to look in the .tex -file used to produce the PDF. More specifically at table 1. Matras are displayed there (vowels, leftmost column).

Comment: Sorry, *rightmost* column (of "Vowels" in Table 1, I meant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by the poster in an updated to the question.